How to estimate probability of detecting a disease/confidence in a variant prevalence estimate from a single cross-sectional sample?
How can I calculate the likelihood of detection of a disease circulating within a population at a given background prevalence (say 5%) from samples from set number of individuals (e.g. 300)?
Additionally, how could I calculate confidence intervals around the prevalence estimate from testing the samples? For example if 20 samples came back positive from the 300 sampled.

Welcome to Cross Validated! As these are pretty standard matters in statistics, it seems like this might be related to a self-study program or a homework assignment. It's OK to ask questions like that here, but please see this page and this page for guidance about how to ask. What works best is if you edit the question to show your attempts to work the problem through so far. Then we can give hints on how to proceed. Also, please add the self-study tag to the question.

It depends on what you mean by "likelihood of detection of a disease circulating within a population"? Do you mean finding at least $\underline{1 \: positive}$ case in your sample? Or finding at least $\underline{1 \: truly \: positive}$ case in the sample? Or finding $\underline {all \: truly \: positive}$ cases in your sample? Or??
In all cases, you will need to know the sensitivity and specificity of your test (see wikipedia's very good discussion). If you do not have these, there is nothing you can do; and your question does not mention that you do. (note: as a general rule, it is not productive to ask questions on CV, but fail to mention relevant "details"; when in doubt, provide rather more that less information).
You may also want to look at the term PPV, i.e. Positive Predictive Value. Start with wikipedia again; it is a very good start. The PPV tells you how likely a positive result from your test is to be truly positive. You will find that with a prevalence of 5%, it is rather low, lower probably than you would expect. This is due to the [base rate paradox][3], or false positive paradox. When the prevalence is low, the PPV of any diagnostic test is actually quite low; this is why screening of the general population is almost never a good idea.
The PPV has a companion, NPV, or Negative Predictive Value, which tells you how likely a negative test result is to be truly negative. When the prevalence is low, the NPV is actually boosted,but is quite low when the prevalence is high (e.g. when you test a highly symptomatic population).
PPV and NPV tell you how much faith you should have in your test results. This does not seem to quite be your question, but it is close and in fact more interesting; would you really want to get positive results, if most of them are false positives?
You also ask how to "calculate confidence intervals around the prevalence estimate from testing the sample". For that, you also need a gold standard result (a test which is essentially correct 100% of the time), or some other way to know the clinical truth (i.e. which subject was really positive or really negative). Your question does not mention that you have access to this clinical truth.
Also, this of course assumes that your sample of 300 is truly random over the general population.
Now, you can still derive an estimate of the prevalence, if you have the sensitivity and specificity of the test. Take the number of positive and negative cases (P & N) you had in your sample of 300; extract the number of true positives (TP) from the formula for sensitivity, and do the same for the number of true negatives (TN). Use the fact that P=TP+FP, and N=TN+FN, and you should end up with 2 equations with 2 unknowns. Just solve it, and you will have the TP value, in that sample of 300 (TN, TP). That gives you an approximation of the prevalence, $\frac {TP} {TP+TN+FP+FN}$ (only an approximation, because in your sample, you certainly did not observe the exact declared sensitivity and specificity of your test, or exact prevalence - but something close to it).
Now, this estimate of the prevalence is just a binomial count. So you could compute a binomial CI around it. But I would not trust it; too many approximations. I certainly would not call it a 95% confidence interval (or any other value). I would just stick with the estimate.
[3]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_rate_fallacy#:~:text=An%20example%20of%20the%20base,classifier%20has%20a%20low%20precision).
